# Set Auth Headers in APIConnect

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect, openwhisk

I'm experimenting with APIConnect and would like to be able to invoke an OpenWhisk action. As far as I can tell, in order to do this I need to set the Authorization header with my token. The only options I can see under both the Invoke and Proxy policies is to use basic authentication.

Regardless of the OpenWhisk piece, in order for APIConnect to be a usable product for me I need to be able to set Headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a **Set Variable** policy in your API Connect flow and call `message.headers.myheadername` to set header values.

This article shows how:
https://developer.ibm.com/apiconnect/2016/07/06/securing-apic-bm-app-httpheaders/

and the relevant documentation:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFS6T/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/rapim_cli_policies_setvariable.html

Comment: Thanks, your help is appreciated

Comment: You should also check out the built-in experimental API support recently enabled in OpenWhisk itself. For simple use cases, it works well. Doesn't give you all of the management features, but for just putting a simple API facade on your Actions, it fits nicely.